# 'MONGO_USER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

I'm following NodeJS Tutorial on Udemy
I got the error when I tried this code

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-complete-guide",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Complete Node.js Guide",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "MONGO_USER=MonkeyKing MONGO_PASSWORD=loveguitar4ever MONGO_DEFAULT_DATABASE=message STRIPE_KEY=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 node app.js",
    "start-server": "node app.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "MonkeyKing",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^2.0.3",
    "csurf": "^1.9.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.17",
    "multer": "^1.4.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "^0.2.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.8.3",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "sequelize": "^5.0.0-beta.11",
    "stripe": "^6.12.1"
  }
}
```

the error is:

```
'MONGO_USER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
sk_live_51GekpQCukpHeumjmDZhZiXzC5F6SaltbPDxQGLPE9sswmFWknSZL87m1a7ktjnpm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodejs-complete-guide@1.0.0 start script.      GO_PASSWORD=loveguitar4ever MONGO_DE
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely addiSaltbPDxQGLPE9sswmFWknSZL87m1a7ktjImtional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MonkeyKing\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-19T01_23_24_946Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your code from a UNIX-like shell, not from Windows' `cmd.exe`. The syntax of prefixing a command with variable assignments is not understood by `cmd`.

Use the Git Bash for example. I assume you already have Git installed (if not, I bet you will have to do that very soon anyway).

To get an even more Linux-y environment, I'd suggest using [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-wsl2) for web development in the first place, though.

For this specific case: You could also remove the variable assignments from the `start` script and run them manually before starting the app, using `set MONGO_USER=MonkeyKing` etc., and remember doing that every time that you open a new shell (possibly creating a batch file). Alternatively move it into a `.env` file and use the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to load it.

Comment: I dont know how to use UNIX-like shell, I've just learn about coding :( I'm following the tutorial on Udemy, and i'm using VSCode
I'll try using .env 
thank you alot!